# Are All Node "callback" Functions Potentially Asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm a (relative) node newbie getting in the system, and all the enthusiasm in the community for "just write callbacks, everything's asynchronous and event driven, don't worry!" has left me a little confused as to the control flow within a single program (or in more node-ish terms, the control flow during the handling of a single request in a larger program)

If I have the following program running under node

```
var foo = function(){
    console.log("Called Foo");
};

var bar = function(){
    console.log("Called Bar");
};

var doTheThing = function(arg1, callback){
    callback();
};

doTheThing(true, function() {
    foo();
});
bar();
```

Is there **any** chance that `foo` will execute **after** `bar`?  When I run the program via the command line locally, it's always

```
Called Foo
Called Bar
```

but I see so many warnings from well intended evangelists along the lines of *don't assume your callback will be called when you think it will*, that I'm unclear if they're just warning me about library implementation details, or if node.js does something weird/special when you use a function object as parameter.

Comment: There is no chance. Everything you have is synchronous. The problem comes when you use asynchronous callbacks (like `setTimeout` race conditions), or when a library you utilize is using asynchronous things (like jQuery `$.Deferred` objects). **EDIT:** I realized you're mainly talking about node, but I don't see why there would be any difference...I hope I'm not wrong! But there shouldn't be a reason why the order would be different unless you're using asynchronous features **specifically** (which your code is not)

Comment: @Ian I'm pretty sure you're right, but I've been doing this long enough to never assume anything about new tech unless I've tested the h—l out of it and gotten confirmation from peers.

Comment: Hey, that's why I commented, hoping more people would join and discuss :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no chance. Not for that code.

If you're writing your own functions, or if you have access to the code, you don't need to assume, you know whether everything's synchronous or otherwise, but if you don't have access to the code, or haven't yet read it, then no, you can't assume callbacks are going to be synchronous.

It's however *bad practice* to make assumptions like that for two reasons, first is that just because it's synchronous now doesn't mean somebody else, or forgetful future you can't change it later, and secondly, because if it's all synchronous, why are you/they using callbacks in the first place? The entire point of callbacks is to allow for the possibility of asynchronous calls. Using callbacks and then acting like they're always going to be synchronous, even if you know that's the case, makes your code confusing for anybody else coming in.

Comment: Re: *if it's all synchronous, why are you/they using callbacks in the first place* — passing anonymous functions around has a long and hallowed history in some corners of the programming world, irrespective of whether code is executed synchronously or asynchronously.

Comment: True. Things like php's usort or backbone's sorting functions take functions and are synchronous, and need to be treated quite differently. I guess I don't mentally refer to them as "callbacks" because the issues they have are different. You still need to be super careful of scope and not making assumptions about when your callback is going to get called however.

Answer (score 2):

## No

Your sample code is 100% synchronous, single-threaded, simple top-to-bottom. But that's because you don't do any I/O, don't have any real asynchronous calls, and don't use `process.nextTick`, `setTimeout`, or `setInterval`. To more realistically simulate async calls do something like:

```
function fakeAsync(name, callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback(null, name);
  }, Math.random() * 5000);
}

function logIt(error, result) {
  console.log(result);
}

fakeAsync('one', logIt);
fakeAsync('two', logIt);
fakeAsync('three', logIt);
```

Run that a few times and you'll see out-of-order results sometimes.

Comment: "sometimes"? About 5/6 of the time :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any chance that foo will execute after bar?

In your current code, no. Although your `doTheThing` function has an asynchronous function signature (i.e. it takes a callback as the last argument, which to an outsider with no knowledge about the function's implementation would suggest that it's asynchronous), it's actually fully synchronous, and `callback` will be called without yielding to the runtime.

*However*

You really have no reason to give your `doTheThing` code an asynchronous signature, *unless* you're accommodating for introducing real async behavior into `doTheThing` at some point. And at that point, you have a problem, because the order in which `foo` and `bar` are called will flip.

In my opinion, there are only two good ways of writing code like you do: Either make it set in stone that `doTheThing` will be synchronous (most importantly: that it won't be dependent on I/O), which means that you can simply return from the function:

```
doTheThing = function(arg1){
   return null
};
doTheThing()
foo()
bar()
```

or change the stub implementation of `doTheThing` directly to include a call to `setImmediate`, i.e.

```
var doTheThing = function(arg1, callback){
   setImmediate(function() { callback(); );
};
```

Note that this can also be written as

```
var doTheThing = function(arg1, callback){
   setImmediate(callback);
};
```

but that's just because at this moment, callback does not take any arguments. The first version is more close to what you had.

As soon as you do this, `bar` will always be called before `foo`, and it has now become safe to introduce async functionality into `doTheThing`.

Comment: Re: "asynchronous function signature" — is it a node.js convention that a parameter named `callback` signals asynchronous behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be considered a convention per se. It's just that normally, when library authors expose "synchronous" functionality (i.e. something that just does number-crunching) it will typically be exposed with a synchronous signature, because that's easier to use. Common sense, really. Let's keep it at that *I* expect a callback to be called asynchronously, and would be non-plussed if a function in a particular library doesn't, and I somehow had to find out the hard way. I'd file a bug report about it too. IMO, good stubs for asynchronous code make use of `setImmediate` or similar.

Comment: I'm not aware of any functions in Node core that violate this rule. The "sync" functions in Node core all have a synchronous function signature (i.e. they just return the result). In that sense, I think Node core sets some expectations for proper behavior.

Comment: Some good reading: [Honour thy async signature](http://markdawson.tumblr.com/post/43705616205/honour-thy-async-signature). "Well in node, if your function has an async signature you should always make sure it is async, you should always honour the asynchronous expectation a caller may have assumed is always implicit."

Comment: @AlanStorm ping. (not sure if you'd see this otherwise)

Comment: I saw it, and appreciate the cultural briefing.  Without wanting to prompt a longer discussion, there are legit uses of synchronous callbacks — think about the chaos if the string object's  `replace` method wasn't synchronous.

Comment: @AlanStorm I don't get your point. `String.prototype.replace` has a synchronous signature. It doesn't have a callback.

Comment: Pretty sure we're on the same page Meryn — just talking past each other. Whenever you (where "you" is the node community) says "a callback", I hear "treating a function as a first class object and passing it into another function to call".  In other words, stuff like the second argument to `replace`. (str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function[, Non-standard flags]))  From what I'm learning when node folks say "a callback", they mean "a function parameter named callback that's also function".

Comment: @AlanStorm Sorry, I forgot all about this functionality of `replace`! I'm not sure how often this "replacer function" is referred to as a callback, but it certainly could be. Still, in my mind, the `replace` function has a synchronous signature, because it returns its results. Asynchronous functions do not return results. In Node.js "callback" often means that particular function that takes the place of things that would be done with `return` (and `throw`) in the synchronous world. A callback being called often signifies the end of some processing.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! Question: what if there was a bunch more code after `bar()`, will it all execute before `foo()`? What determines when `foo()` will get its turn again?